# LDAP Auth from Webserver to Windows Active Directory

Tags: php, windows, ssl, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a Windows Domain Controller (AD) with valid cert structure from a Windows 10 Xampp Apache webserver (Client) setup. The LDAP-module is activated.
If I try to connect without SSL/TLS just on ldap:// its working fine. This is my ApiController:

```
username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$config = new Config();
$ldapConfig = $config->ldapConfig;
$adServer = "ldaps://" . $ldapConfig['adServer'];

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer, 389);
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, 1);
ldap_start_tls($ldap);

$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldapConfig['dc'] . "\\" . $username, $password);

if (!($bind)) {
     throw new ApiException('401 Unauthorized', ApiException::AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
}
```

```
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 00000257419F0D50 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 00000257419F0D50 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 00000257419F0D50 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 00000257419F0D50 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 1 all 1
read1msg: ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 1 message type extended-result
read1msg: ld 00000257419F0D50 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 1
request done: ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_extended_result
ldap_parse_result
ldap_msgfree
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
TLS certificate verification: depth: 1, err: 20, subject: /C=DE/L=XXX/O=XXX/OU=XXX/CN=XXX Issuing V2, issuer: /C=DE/L=XXX/OU=XXX/O=XXX/CN=XXX Root V2
TLS certificate verification: Error, unable to get local issuer certificate
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:unknown CA
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate).
ldap_err2string
[Wed Sep 30 12:52:15 2020] PHP Warning:  ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error in C:\git\invoice-workflow\src\api\v1\Controller\ApiController.php on line 47
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_result ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 2
wait4msg ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 2 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 2 all 1
** ld 00000257419F0D50 Connections:
* host: svr100dc.alfru.net  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed Sep 30 12:52:15 2020


** ld 00000257419F0D50 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 00000257419F0D50 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 00000257419F0D50 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 00000257419F0D50 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 00000257419F0D50 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 00000257419F0D50 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_err2string
[Wed Sep 30 12:52:15 2020] PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\git\invoice-workflow\src\api\v1\Controller\ApiController.php on line 49
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
[Wed Sep 30 12:52:15 2020] 127.0.0.1:55486 [401]: /src/api/v1/invoice
```

> /C=DE/L=XXX/O=XXX/OU=XXX/CN=XXX Issuing V2 not the real cert...

Some things that i tryed:

- Changed the port to 686 or 3269
- Added cert to own (trusted) certs in Windows mmc
- Changed ldaps:// to ldap://

Comment: Have you tried setting `$adServer = "ldaps://" . $ldapConfig['adServer'] . ':686'; `as described in the docs?

Comment: Yes. As described in the "Some things i tried".

Comment: you didn't specify where you changes the port. As you specified the port in the second parameter to `ldap_connect` I assumed that you chamged it there. But as the docs explain that parameter isn't used when you use an LDAP URI as you do. Hence the question whether you specified the port in the URI. But as you are using `ldap_start_tls` the port has to be 389 and the scheme `ldap` anyhow...